# Why does learning Elementalist skill's require amount of sp spent on sorceress skill?

Tags: dragon-nest

First of all, this is not a complaint or anything, I'm pretty new about this game, and having hesitation while building my character.

Right now I have a lv 32 Elementalist, and I'm pretty confused when learning new skills, because it requires me to spend 40 or something sp on sorceress skill trees, but I found nothing actually worth to spend sp on in sorceress skill tree.... Most of them are active skills which I rarely use, and even the passive skills are pretty useless. I want to spend more sp on elementalist skills but I'm forced to spend lots of my sp on sorceress skills, which is pretty annoying....

So my question is: Is it really mandatory to spend those sp on sorceress skill tress, is there any workaround? If there's n, which sorcesress skills should I max for PVE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it really mandatory to spend those sp on sorceress skill tress, is
>   there any workaround?

Yes it is mandatory. I'm not sure which version you play but as the game has many releases but I will assume you play the north american version.

You will want to have 45 and 65 points in your first tree and second tree respectively. This will allow you to utilize all your skills.

Now your second question:

> If there's n, which sorcesress skills should I max for PVE?

This is a little more difficult to answer. Each character presently has different sets of class changes they can undergo. For Sorceress the first class change set is Mystic and Elementalists, As an elementalist you can change into an Ice Witch or Pyromancer.

Assuming you want to become an Ice Witch, this is one of the more popular builds floating around:
[image]
[image]
[image]

If you want to be a pyromancer I don't really know too much about the class; however, the popular choices and discussion boards lead me to believe that this is the general blue print for a good build:

[image]
[image]
[image]

### Before you run off though, you need to know....

If you are leveling up a character you will realize that have a surplus of points. You are advised to hold onto those points until you can invest them. You can use them in miscellenous skills and reskill your character later; however, depending on the version you get you may not have many free resets. I believe you get one at 14, another at 32. Another at 40 and finally one at 58. You may also PvP and get an unlimited reset scroll at for reaching the rank of scout.

I advise that you experiment as much as you possibly can though because it is a well known fact that in the case of dragon nest builds suit play styles and there is no one build fits all players type of thing.